# I'm getting a unassigned variable error at the account1 after the GetTransfer. I can not figure out what logic error i have messed up on

Tags: c++

Getting an unassigned variable error after the GetTransfer portion of the code. It is claiming account1 is the unassigned variable but from what i can see i have declared it. i have tried multiple times to correct it and i just can figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
// Chance Pinkerton
// December 3, 2013
// CaseProject2Chapter3
struct bankInfo
{
    int accountNum;
    double startBal; 
    double endBal;
};

int main()
{
        bankInfo account1;
        bankInfo account2;
        double transferAmt;
        int GetAccount1();
        int GetAccount2();
        double GetBal1();
        double GetBal2();
        double GetTransfer();

        account1.accountNum = GetAccount1();

        while (account1.accountNum < 1000 || account1.accountNum > 9999)
        {
            cout << "Error. That account does not exsist." << endl;
            account1.accountNum = GetAccount1();
        }

        GetBal1();

        account2.accountNum = GetAccount2();

        while (account2.accountNum < 1000 || account2.accountNum > 9999)
        {
            cout << "Error. That account number doesnt exsist." << endl;


             account2.accountNum = GetAccount2();
        }

        if (account2.accountNum == account1.accountNum)
            {
                cout << "Error. Account numbers can not be the same " << endl;
                account2.accountNum = GetAccount2();
            }


        GetBal2();

        transferAmt = GetTransfer();

        account1.accountNum = (account1.accountNum % 5) + (account1.accountNum * 10);
        account2.accountNum = (account2.accountNum % 5) + (account2.accountNum * 10);
        account1.endBal;
        account2.endBal;

        while (account1.endBal < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error. Account balance can not be negative." << endl;
            GetTransfer();

            if (account1.endBal < 10)
            {
            cout << "Warning. Account balance will be below $10.00 " << endl;
            }
        }

        account1.endBal = account1.startBal - transferAmt;
        account2.endBal = account2.startBal + transferAmt;

        cout << "Account number 1: " << account1.accountNum << endl;
        cout << "Starting balance: " << account1.startBal << endl;
        cout << "Ending balance: " << account1.endBal << endl;
        cout << "Account number 2: " << account2.accountNum << endl;
        cout << "Starting balance: " << account2.startBal << endl;
        cout << "Ending balance: " << account2.endBal << endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int GetAccount1()
{
    int accountNum;
    cout << "Please enter your account number " << endl;
    cin >> accountNum;
    return accountNum;
}

int GetAccount2()
{
    int accountNum;
    cout << "Please enter the second account number " << endl;
    cin >> accountNum;
    return accountNum;
}

double GetBal1()
{
    double startBal;
    cout << "Enter your account balance " << endl;
    cin >> startBal;
    return startBal;
}

double GetBal2()
{
    double startBal;
    cout << "Enter the second account balance " << endl;
    cin >> startBal;
    return startBal;
}

double GetTransfer()
{
    double transferAmt;
    cout << "How much would you like to transfer to the second account " << endl;
    cin >> transferAmt;
    return transferAmt;
}
```

Comment: Please parse this down to only the relevant bits of code...

Comment: First, function declarations need to be outside of main. EDIT: not technically true but as @chris said it won't work as you want it to the way you have it ^^ Second, in the line `GetTransfer();`, where are you trying to put the result?

Comment: @CommanderCorianderSalamander, That's not completely correct. The declarations can go in `main`, but they won't match up properly with the definitions below `main`.

Comment: Also, I think the more serious issue (and maybe the real problem) is that you do this: `account1.endBal; account2.endBal; while (account1.endBal < 0)` - you haven't assigned anything to `account1.endBal` or `account2.endBal` and then you try to use them in loop conditions. What do you expect to happen there?

Comment: You have several places where you don't assign return values and other random issues like `account1.endBal;`.  To get rid of the warning you could add a default constructor to your `bankInfo` object, but frankly that's probably the least of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

These two statements do exactly nothing, and are likely the source of the warning the compiler is giving you:

```
    account1.endBal;
    account2.endBal;
```

Furthermore, I think you need to actually capture the return value of `GetTransfer()` here, perhaps into `transferAmt`:

```
        GetTransfer();
```

You probably need to rethink this entire `while` loop, especially taking into account how `transferAmt` relates to `account1.endBal`:

```
    while (account1.endBal < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error. Account balance can not be negative." << endl;
        GetTransfer();

        if (account1.endBal < 10)
        {
        cout << "Warning. Account balance will be below $10.00 " << endl;
        }
    }
```

For example, you don't want to update `endBal` until you know the transfer will succeed.  Furthermore, your low-balance warning is in completely the wrong place.

Comment: I didn't originally have those in the code i put them there to initialize the variables which didn't work. i took out the first two statements and i still get the error. Also thank you for pointing out the low-balance warning and the GetTransfer() i fixed that portion of code

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful input. I figured out i needed to use account1.startBal = GetBal1(); to initialize the variable. Also @Joe Z thank you for your help on the other logic errors i made, it was very helpful and i appreciated your comments.